# 255.255.255.255 broadcast address meaning

Tags: netmask

Lets suppose we have a computer with three NICs:

NIC_1: 172.16.1.1/24

NIC_2: 192.168.1.1/24

NIC_3: 103.55.34.32/24

We send a packet with the destination IP address being 255.255.255.255.

1) if the default gw is on the 103.55.34/24 network, will the packet be sent through NIC_3 or will the packet be sent through every NIC?

2) If we make an assumption that the whole internet is a one big network and this network network address is 0.0.0.0/0, the 255.255.255.255 address looks like a broadcast address for the whole network (for the internet), right?

3) What would be the meaning of a network address like this: 1.2.0.0/0? (is this correct and if not, why not)

Comment: `1.2.0.0/0` cannot be a network address because a network address has all the host bits set to zero. Since `/0` means all the bits are host bits, the only valid `/0` network address is `0.0.0.0/0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It will be sent through the first interface in the route table that matches the destination, evaluated in the order static route>route>gateway>metric. If you type `route print` you'll see something similar to the following:

   > ```
   > Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
   > [Loads of entries for your various NICs, routes and static routes]
   > 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    103.55.34.254   103.55.34.32       1
   > Default Gateway:       103.55.34.254
   > ```

   Indicating that the broadcast/multicast test ping will use your NIC_3
2. Assuming you had a network 0.0.0.0/0, then yes 255.255.255.255 WOULD be the broadcast address. The Internet however is not one big network, it's a series of interconnected completely separate networks (hence inter-net!)

Comment: See my answer here for an explanation of the 255.255.255.255 broadcast address: http://serverfault.com/questions/338593/allow-broadcast-to-255-255-255-255-through-tmg-vpn-for-netbios-resolution/342162#342162